# How can I use Shiro SSO

Tags: java, apache, shiro

how should I configure SSO shiro in web application In my web app I want to access another weba app . But  I am new to shiro and having difficulties with SSO.. So anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you started with the Apache Shiro documentation on integration with a CAS SSO server?

[Integrating Apache Shiro with CAS SSO server](http://shiro.apache.org/cas.html)